# Iranian drones in Ukraine, Chinese parts, and sanctions

Tags: armed-conflict, sanctions, drones

I heard that Russia uses Iranian drones, Shahed-136. I wonder if it doesn't have any Chinese parts and if so, does it affect sanctions on China?

Comment: It also uses TMS320 CPU from USA and fuel pump from Poland, so sanctions for China may not be the first thing to care about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HESA_Shahed_136), the Shahed-136 uses an off-the-shelf Chinese made engine, the [MD550](http://www.uavstar.com/Products/Engine/Engine_e.htm).  This is made by a Chinese company Beijing Micropilot Association.  Checking the [Entity List of sanctioned companies](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/documents/regulations-docs/2326-supplement-no-4-to-part-744-entity-list-4/file), I don't see sanctions currently in effect against this company.